# "See vote breakout" dialog confusing

Tags: discussion, privileges, recent-activity

Here the user presses "See vote breakout" but it apparently is not a button.

[image: See votes breakout]

And the second "See votes", the one I highlighted in magenta, is apparently just a dialog title.

Anyway, the whole rectangle causes the browser cursor to become a finger, etc.

It is very confusing and one would need to explore the HTML to figure out what is intended. Perhaps the only thing to click on is "Learn more."

```
<div class="popup-white"><p>See vote breakout</p><div class="actions h-auto p16">
<span class="rep-number">550/1,000 Rep.</span><a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user" 
class="s-btn s-btn__filled float-right" title="Learn more">Learn more</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, that just happens to be the most confusing privilege, and some might say useless but that's for a different discussion.

The confusion in your case appears to be because the privilege name itself is actually "established user", as can be seen by clicking the "Learn more" link. So ideally, the tracker and dialog title would show the privilege name, then the description can be indeed "See vote breakout" as this is the only privilege given.

You can start a new feature request asking for this, though don't expect such thing to be done any time soon. (Being very minor, and there are thousands of other bug reports and feature requests in the backlog.)

Comment: "breakout" isn't even the right word - probably "breakdown" or "split" is what was intended. But that's still vague to a user who might not even know about down-votes yet. Should probably say "See up and down votes on a post" but, I agree, wouldn't be top of my list.

Comment: @AaronBertrand unless you have access to that code? ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I'll leave it to others who have more of a grasp than me, to suggest fixes.